# Как сделать удаление объекта по нажатию кнопки с onClick через mutation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

есть код с graphql в bff и есть в части приложения

данная функция описана следующим образом:

*shema.js:*

```
type Mutation {
    deleteCart(id: Int): [Cart]
}
```

*index.js:*

```
deleteCart: (_, args) => {
    carts = carts.filter((c) => c.id !== args.id);
    return carts;
  }
```

*как объявлена в query:*

```
export const CART_ITEMS = gql`
mutation DeleteCart ($id: Int) {
    deleteCart(id: $id) {
        id, title, text, size, price, image
    }}`
```

когда пробую сделать это внутри графического интерфейса, то выдает ошибку:

```
Assignment to constant variable
```

также не совсем понятно как реализовать срабатывание через нажатия кнопки onClick

заранее спасибо!

Comment: `carts` - константа?

Comment: carts это название массива с которым идет работа и в котором необходимо удалить объект

Comment: Вы не ответили на вопрос.

Comment: `let carts = [...]`
переменная

Comment: Попробуйте изменить `export const CART_ITEMS = ...` на `export let CART_ITEMS = ...`

Comment: Также вам к ознакомлению: [TypeError: invalid assignment to const "x"(недопустимое назначение const "x")](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Invalid_const_assignment)